# turn reflect into comparable data

Tags: if-statement, reflection, go, types

I want to be able to compare the type of an object using `reflect`. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    tst := "cat"
    if reflect.TypeOf(tst) == string {
        fmt.Println("It's a string!")
    }

}
```

This gives me an error `type string is not an expression`. How can I fix this **only using reflect**? (no type switches, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple options:

use `Kind`:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(tst).Kind() == reflect.String {
    fmt.Println("It's a string!")
}
```

use `TypeOf` another string:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(tst) == reflect.TypeOf("") {
    fmt.Println("It's a string!")
}
```

However, personally I'd prefer a type switch or type check (i.e. `if _, ok := tst.(string); ok {...}`

Comment: Third option: `if reflect.TypeOf(tst).Name() == "string"`

Comment: For your last point, wouldn't type check only work if `tst` was of interface type?

Comment: @Akavall yes but I'm assuming it's already an interface type if we're doing this sort of checks